# C++ Read an input file

Tags: c++, file, input, iostream

i'm having problems reading a file and saving the values.

So the input file contains:

> 3 5
>
> W2 R3 W3 R4

And what i want is this:

> F = 3
>
> P = 5
>
> char Ac[] = {'W','R','W','R'};
>
> int acc[] = {2,3,3,4};

I already have the F = 3 and P = 5 but i don't know how to separate the other Strings.

I hope you can help me!

Comment: Is there a reason you are using parallel arrays rather than an array (or vector) of a struct?

Comment: bc this is for virtual memory simulation, i have to read if is Write or Read and the number of Page and my first program was like that, instead of reading from a file, so i can see if it works, but if there is a better way is welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can read character by character, skipping whitespaces.

Or you could read in a string, then split the string:

```
std::string  rw_text;
std::vector<char> Ac;
std::vector<int>  acc;
//...
while (input_file >> rw_text)
{
  const char letter = rw_text[0];
  const int number = rw_text[1] - '0';
  Ac.push_back(letter);
  acc.push_back(number);
}
```

You could also use a `struct` to keep your letters and numbers together, like a `pair`.

```
struct Letter_Number
{
  char letter;
  int  number;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Letter_Number& ln);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Letter_Number& ln)
{
  input >> ln.letter;
  input >> ln.number;
  return input;
}

//...
std::vector<Letter_Number> database;
Letter_Number ln;
//...
while (input_file >> ln)  
{
  database.push_back(ln);
}
```

A structure will keep the letters associated with their numbers.  In a parallel array, you could have different offsets or the pair won't line up.

Also, with having a structure, the letter and number will be on the processor's same data cache line, so your program will be more efficient.  Otherwise the processor will have to load in the `Ac` array, get the value, then load in the `acc` array and load in the character; wasting time reloading the data cache.